# Qt: Show or hide row in QFormLayout containing sublayout

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I can show or hide rows of a `QFormLayout` if each row contains a QLabel and a QWidget.

```
showHideHeaderBtn = QCheckBox("Show")
hbox.addWidget(showHideHeaderBtn)
...

# Simple QFormLayout
self.headerOptForm = QFormLayout()
self.vbox.addLayout(self.headerOptForm)

self.ccEdit = QLineEdit()
self.headerOptForm.addRow("Cc", self.ccEdit)

self.bccEdit = QLineEdit()
self.headerOptForm.addRow("Bcc", self.bccEdit)

self.replyToEdit = QLineEdit()
self.headerOptForm.addRow("ReplyTo", self.replyToEdit)

showHideHeaderBtn.toggled.connect(lambda:
    self.showHideHeaderBtn_clicked(showHideHeaderBtn,
    self.headerOptForm, 2))
```

The corresponding `showHideHeaderBtn_clicked` is given by:

```
def showHideHeaderBtn_clicked(self,toggleBtn,formLayout,ncol):

    nrows = formLayout.rowCount()
    nindex = ncol*nrows

    if toggleBtn.isChecked():
        # Show the lines
        for idx in range(0,nindex):
            widget = formLayout.itemAt(idx).widget()
            widget.show()

    else:
        # Hide the lines
        for idx in range(0,nindex):
            widget = formLayout.itemAt(idx).widget()
            widget.hide()

    return
```

However, when the QFormLayout itself has a layout like so:

```
self.attachForm = QFormLayout()
self.vBox.addLayout(self.attachForm)
...
hbox = QHBoxLayout()
self.attachForm.addRow('',hbox)

browseBtn = QPushButton("Open")
browseBtn.setToolTip("Select File")
browseBtn.clicked.connect(self.browseBtn_clicked)
hbox.addWidget(browseBtn)

addAttachEdit = QLineEdit()
hbox.addWidget(addAttachEdit)

delAttachBtn = QPushButton("x")
delAttachBtn.setFixedSize(15,15)
delAttachBtn.clicked.connect(self.delAttachBtn_clicked)
hbox.addWidget(delAttachBtn)
```

Then the `showHideHeaderBtn_clicked` function fails (because it has a sub-layout) for each row.
How do I modify the `showHideHeaderBtn_clicked` function to show/hide the rows of the `QFormLayout`?

Comment: What about creating a container widget for the QHBoxLayout, and add that widget instead of the layout?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, if I do that, the vertical spacing in-between each of the rows of the QFormLayout is more, because of the widget container.

Comment: That's not the widget, but it's due to the default layout margins, which are automatically applied when a layout is set on a widget. Use `hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments by @musicamante to my question helped me. The final solution is

```
self.attachForm = QFormLayout()
self.vBox.addLayout(self.attachForm)
...
container = QWidget()                # New line 
self.attachForm.addRow('',container) # New line

hbox = QHBoxLayout()
# self.attachForm.addRow('',hbox)    # Old line, commented out
hbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)     # New line
container.setLayout(hbox)            # New line

browseBtn = QPushButton("Open")
browseBtn.setToolTip("Select File")
browseBtn.clicked.connect(self.browseBtn_clicked)
hbox.addWidget(browseBtn)

addAttachEdit = QLineEdit()
hbox.addWidget(addAttachEdit)

delAttachBtn = QPushButton("x")
delAttachBtn.setFixedSize(15,15)
delAttachBtn.clicked.connect(self.delAttachBtn_clicked)
hbox.addWidget(delAttachBtn)
```

The `showHideBtn_clicked()` function is slightly modified to

```
def showHideBtn_clicked(self,toggleBtn,formLayout,ncol):

    nrows = formLayout.rowCount()
    nindex = ncol*nrows

    for idx in range(0,nindex):
        widgetItem = formLayout.itemAt(idx)
        if widgetItem != None:
            widget = widgetItem.widget()

            if toggleBtn.isChecked():
                widget.show()
            else:
                widget.hide()
```

Answer (score 3):

In Qt 6.4 added special method `QtWidgets.QFormLayout.setRowVisible(layout, on)` to hide or show row